# migration from Windows 2008 remote app manager to Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp

I made new server Windows 2012 and wanted to make the same structure for remote app, like rdp installation file for my users as was in Windows 2008. But in Windows 2012 I can do only with a RDWeb to remote app (it is working fine).

Major task is to make link on desktop for some users, they should click and connect to remote app like it was in Windows 2008.
Also I have some arguments to be added to run a program.

One more issue, https certificate error, then i am connecting to RDWeb server.
My company Cert was assigned to RDWeb site, it is in cert imported, but error. Strange.

Could somebody advise me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this covers your first question: http://www.concurrency.com/infrastructure/how-to-deliver-remoteapps-from-windows-server-2012-rds/

In particular, you can specify a group policy and the users will automatically subscribe to the respective workspace. This will lead to icons showing up in the start menu. If you REALLY want them on desktop, then you need a script that puts the shortcuts / files on the desktop and using Scheduled Task interface, set it as a scheduled task on user login.

Certificate error can mean many things - is the cert expired or is the cert for a different domain than what it is used for or is the cert not trusted or ... something else? What is the error that you are getting?